# Declare PHP array element as class object

Tags: php, arrays, types, element, declare

I have an array:

```
$arr = [
   "banana" => new Fruit("banana"),
   "apple" => new Fruit("apple")
];

class Fruit {
  private $name;
  function __construct ($fruit_name) {
      $this->name = $fruit_name;
  }

  public function write() {
      echo $this->name;
  }
}

//Print
$arr["banana"]->write(); // result: banana
```

Everything's fine, but my IDE (PHPStorm 9.0) warning the last row above: method "write" not found. It didn't recognize the data type of array's elements.

How can I declare array's element as class object, so my IDE not warning about that?

Thank you!